# Frequency Sensitive Switch

Tags: digital-logic, switches, frequency, logic-gates

A legacy product we are making uses this obsolete Frequency Sensitive Switch, [Consumer Micro FX-301L](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/CML/mXvyzzw.pdf).

The switch is setup such that it switches on (-12V) at 2000Hz +-100Hz and switches off at 250Hz. Packaged in a TO-100 can.

We need to replace this component, but there is nothing I can find that is even close to this type of operation. I've never seen a component like this before!

The IC uses a combination of amplifiers, monostable timers and comparators and has some extra logic to configure the setup.

In circuit, its output goes to a FET which is gated to the output of a 7412 flip flop which i believe is used to illuminate a status indicator lamp. [image]

The diodes drawn on (D15 and unlabeled) are not fitted.

Are there alternatives? Do we need to design a daughter board to replace this?If so, what would be the smallest footprint circuit that we could use?

Comment: How my redesign are you allowed to do? MCU seems suitable for this job.

Comment: A micro controller with multi channel ADC and some SW should be able to do that.

Comment: Re-design is the last resort option. These are large and crowded old school PCBs which we have little digital gerber data of. Most of these are made from film artwork.

Comment: @Oldfart - Why an ADC. Seems it would simply be better to amplify the input AC signal to digital clipping levels that are then applied to a timer/counter channel for measurement of the frequency.

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes that's how the original device does it. Except on silicon which is nice and small.

Comment: Because you can use two ADC channels for the VR1.

Comment: A small SMT micro could fit on a 1/2" square PCB with similar pinout to original. Problem is, programming them - unless done by DigiKey, etc.

Comment: I agree with @rdtsc but programming shouldn't be a big issue. What volumes are we talking about?

Comment: Single digits volume but our delivery date is very close. SMT MCU looks like the only option.

Answer (score 1):

If I was tasked with the design requirement to come up with a replacement for the FX301L I would be looking to make a small daughter board that could be retrofitted into the location that the old part was mounted. There are some mixed signal ICs available that include a microcontroller that could be deployed to make the daughter board.

I would take a look at the Microchip PIC16F570 device which includes an MCU along with a built in dual opamp and a dual comparator. A timer is also available to be used along with software to measure the frequency. The device is available in a 4mm by 4mm UQFN package and can operate with a supply voltage of 2.0 to 5.5 volts. The opamps could be used to amplify the input AC signal to clipped logic levels so that the signal can then be used by the timer logic for the frequency measurement. The part in the UQFN package sells for less than one US$ in quantity 1.

Comment: I just want to mention that startup time might become an issue for MCUs. Maybe something along the lines of a GreenPak is better suited.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into the FX101L from Island Labs.

https://islandlabs.eu/cml-fx101.html

It looks to be very a very similar part to what you are attempting to replace.

[image]

Picture Source: See above link.

Comment: The FX101L is also an obsolete device from CML, same as the FX301L we are trying to replace.